# Writing plist with existing data in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have a option to upload the plist file to iCloud in my app. When app is deleted and installed back the contents has to retained. This what I have been trying and I don't have any issue upload/retrieve from iCloud. I get plist details as NSData from cloud. Now the problem is I have write back this data to my plist exists already.

```
NSArray *paths           = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir   = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *root          = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Receipts.plist"];
```

I get plist contents from cloud as NSData and after converting to NSString this is what I get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Amount</key>
        <string>USD 1500.00</string>
        <key>Category</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Currency</key>
        <string>USD</string>
        <key>Date</key>
        <string>Thu 30 Oct,2014</string>
        <key>DateSort</key>
        <string>2014/10/30</string>
        <key>Merchant</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Payment</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Purpose</key>
        <string>-</string>
        <key>SubCategory</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>TimeStamp</key>
        <string>Thu 30 Oct,2014 14:42:47</string>
        <key>Tips</key>
        <string>0.00</string>
        <key>UDDate1</key>
        <string>Thu 30 Oct,2014</string>
        <key>UDDate2</key>
        <string>Thu 30 Oct,2014</string>
        <key>UDNumber1</key>
        <string>0.00</string>
        <key>UDNumber2</key>
        <string>0.00</string>
        <key>UDNumber3</key>
        <string>0.00</string>
        <key>UDText1</key>
        <string>-</string>
        <key>UDText2</key>
        <string>-</string>
        <key>UDText3</key>
        <string>-</string>
        <key>Uploaded</key>
        <string>upload</string>
        <key>Value</key>
        <string>0</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I find issue while writing this old content back. How to write those contents back to this plist which is empty?

Comment: I don't understand.Can you explain breifly?

Comment: The above plist detail is retrieved from iCloud. I need to write this in my plist that exists already when app is deleted and reinstalled back. @user3182143

Comment: Do you want to just check whether the plist is already exists or not?

Comment: no ! I need to save this plist content got from iCloud to a plist file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. Your plist is an array,so save the array to file.

```
//read from file
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:root];
//wirte to file
NSArray *sourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
BOOL success = [sourceArray writeToFile:root atomically:YES];
```

Comment: NSData *fileData = documentData; ->plist content from cloud is here.  I convert this to string and I add to "arrayWithContentsOfFile". But no luck !

Comment: How did you save the file and how did you upload the file to iCloud?

Comment: You can try [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9imb0n10vnhmzlx/PlistTest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: "NSString *filename12 = @"ReceiptorBP.plist";...""NSData *dataReturn = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:root];" ...[self uploadDocumentWithcontents:dataReturn name:filename12  result:^(BOOL success) -> upload function.

Comment: You can save the string to a file,and read an nsarray from the file

Comment: [string writeToFile:root atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

Comment: last code no luck! I'll try your example & try to make it!